# How to free memory after winform closed

Tags: .net, winforms, ironpython

I'm using ironpython to graph my binary data.

So, when I start my main form(wpf) and load the data, my memory usage was around 600 MB, after I opened my graph window (winform), my memory usage went up to 800 MB, but after I closed my graph window, the memory usage is still 800 MB, it does not change. How am I going to release the memory usage after the current winform is closed ?

I have tried to use GC.collect after run the application,

and tried to use self.disposed in window close event handler, they all doesn't work.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(graph_plot)
System.GC.Collect()
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Window close event

```
def EH_FormClose(self,sender,object):
    self.Dispose(True)
```

I am expecting to relase the memory usage of this winform, so that I can have spare memory for my next graph.

I'm not sure if the memory is used by winform or ironpython. but when I test the program from console in ironpython, the memory works as I expected.

Also, I have 8GB memory, but the programm throws memory exception when the program uses 1.5 GB memory, is there any way to make use of my memory ?

Comment: If the Garbage Collector isn't freeing memory, then you still have references to objects somewhere.  There is no way to avoid tracing though your code to see what is holding the references.  There is no way we can give you detailed help with the amount of code you have posted.  The "usual" suspect for memory leaks in WPF or WinForms applications are events pointing to handlers on objects that you *think* you released, but the event source keeps the reference alive.  I'd start there.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Hi, Do you mean that if nothing hold the reference of that winform, then when I close the window, the memory will definately be collected by GC?

Comment: Basically, yes. The object graph of references can be very complex though. Sometimes references can hide in unexpected places.

Comment: In addition to what Bradley Uffner said, if you are using Task Manager to monitor memory usage that is not a very accurate way to do so. Also, are you targetting the 32-bit or 64-bit interpreter? If 32-bit, you are probably limited to less than 2 GB of memory, thus the exceptions.